# Object attribute as instance, can't modify or multiply when associated with a slider from controls

Tags: attributes, controls, instance, typeerror, vpython

Using vPython 2.73, I have assigned a mass attribute to a frame. I get the following error when I try to multiply this value by other values:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'instance'

Below is my usage:

machine=frame(mass=15.) #other 3d objects added to this frame

g,c=6.6e-34,3.e8 #constants in float format

(machine.mass*g*c) #this value is of type:float, it prints, saves as any other variable, but traces back error to this statement.

It seems to only have a problem inside an object for the controls module. This statement (machine.mass*g*c) does not give an error when not associated with a slider()

Some of my research indicates that in pre-3.x versions of vPython any user added attribute is an instance and built in ones are genuine objects, but in 3.x versions built in attributes are treated the same as user added ones. (I have to use ver2.73 due to the software on the school computers needed for my presentation.)

Is there any way around this error, while still using a slider object, while still using ver2.73?